# Prove that $TTM$? is a orientable bundle on $TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I know that $TM$ is always orientable bundle. But what is $TTM$?

How try to prove that $TTM$ is a orientable bundle on $TM$.

Comment: As answered below, $TM$ is always an orientable manifold (but the vector bundle $TM \rightarrow M$ need not be orientable _as a vector bundle_, meaning fiber-wise, which is perhaps a concept you haven't come across; this statement is equivalent to $M$ itself being orientable). If your question then is whether $T(TM)$ is orientable _as a manifold_, then the answer is yes, it's of the form $TX$ for $X = TM$, which is a manifold.

Answer (score 7):

No, $TM$ is an orientable bundle if and only if $M$ is an orientable manifold.

You mean $T(TM)$. And that *is* always an orientable bundle: Even when $M$ is non-orientable, $T_{(x,v)}(TM) \cong T_xM \oplus T_xM$ has a canonical orientation.

Comment: Regardless as $M$ orientable or not, $TM$ is always orientable

Comment: No, $TM$ is always orientable as a *manifold*, because $T(TM)$ is an orientable *bundle*. But $TM$ is *not* always an orientable vector bundle.

Comment: No, the tangent bundle $TM$ of any smooth manifold $M$ is orientable, for any smooth manifold $M$ even when $M$ is non- orientable.

Comment: jimbo: I'm not going to argue. You need to do some more reading.

Comment: I'm not going to argue. See Problem 2 chap. 0, do Carmo Riemnnian Geometry.                                                          Prove that the tangent bundle of a differentiable manifold M is orientable (even though may not be).

Comment: Yes, $TM$ is an orientable *manifold*. I've said this to you three times now. The first sentence of your question says it's orientable as a vector bundle. That is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I understand now, thanks for the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

As often it is clearer to put the problem in a more general context.

a) Given a smooth vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$ on the differential manifold $M$, there is an exact sequence of vector bundles on $E$: $$0\to T_v(E)\to T(E)\stackrel {d\pi}{\to }\pi^*(T(M))\to 0         $$ Here $T_v(E)$ is the bundle formed by those tangent vectors which are "vertical", i.e. tangent to the fibers of $\pi$.
Recalling  that for a finite-dimensional vector space  $V$ (seen as a manifold) we have for each $a\in V$ a canonical isomorphism $T_a(V)=V$ we obtain the canonical isomorphism $$T_v(E)=\pi^*(E)$$ and the above exact sequence becomes the fundamental exact sequence of vector bundles on $E$ : $$0\to \pi^*(E)\to T(E)\stackrel {d\pi}{\to }\pi^*(T(M))\to 0    \quad(\bigstar)     $$ Like all exact sequences of smooth vector bundles on a manifold the above exact sequence splits, **alas non canonically**, and we obtain an isomorphism of vector bundles on $E$: $$T(E)\cong \pi^*(E)\oplus \pi^*(T(M))$$

b) Specializing to the case $E=T(M)$ we get an isomorphism of vector bundles on $T(M)$: $$T(T(M))\cong \pi^*(T(M))\oplus \pi^*(T(M))$$

c) To conclude it suffices to recall that given any vector bundle $F\to X$ on a manifold $X$, the vector bundle $F\oplus F$ is orientable, independently of whether the bundle $F$ is or is not orientable.
This shows that $T(T(M))$ is an orientable vector bundle on the manifold $T(M)$, which exactly means  that **$T(M)$ is an orientable manifold**, independently of whether $M$ is or is not an orientable manifold.

**Remark**
The exact sequence $(\bigstar)$ is beautiful, powerful and easy to derive.
Although it is certainly well known to specialists, it is regrettable that  it is not mentioned in any book I know.
I would be very grateful to a user who could indicate a reference for it.

Comment: Very nice and clear answer, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, dear Hanno.

Comment: The exact sequence $\bigstar$ is at least implicit in many sources on connections, though you're correct that for some reason it's often not made explicit. [Here's](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1886) a monograph discussing it explicitly (see 1.2.10 and Chapter 3).

Comment: Dear @aes: actually, the link  does not contain $\bigstar$ but the preliminary exact sequence five lines above in the answer. Anyway connections, a more advanced concept,  are not needed in either of the two exact sequences under discussion  and it is a pity that they are not explained in the basic textbooks  on differential manifolds. That said, the document you refer to is quite interesting and I thank you for posting a link to it .