# Canonical Bundle Isomorphism $T_v(E)\cong \pi^* E$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Given a smooth vector bundle $\pi:E\to M$, the *vertical bundle* $T_v(E)$ is by definition $\ker T\pi$, which is a subbundle of $T(E)$. It is asserted in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083022/prove-that-ttm-is-a-orientable-bundle-on-tm) that there is a canonical isomorphism $$T_v(E)\cong \pi^* E.$$

Georges Elencwajg writes the following:

> Recalling  that for a finite-dimensional vector space  $V$ (seen as a
>   manifold) we have for each $a\in V$ a canonical isomorphism $T_a(V)=V$
>   we obtain the canonical isomorphism $T_v(E)=\pi^*(E)$

I am still unable to see how one obtains the claimed isomorphism and would be thankful for elucidation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical bundle consists of the *fibers* of $E$ as subspaces of $TE$. (This is because we identify the tangent vectors to a vector space, as Georges said, with the vector space itself.) That is, at a point $\xi\in E$, $(T_vE)_\xi = E_{\pi(\xi)}$. Thus, by definition of the pullback bundle, $T_vE = \pi^*E$.